# Does `binding` works with `iterate`?

Tags: clojure

Anything wrong with the code? looks like `binding` doesn't work with `iterate`?

```
(def ^:dynamic *step* 1)

(defn incr [n] (+ n *step*))

(take 3 (binding [*step* 2] (iterate incr 1)))
```

gives

```
'(1 2 3)
```

not

```
'(1 3 5)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `iterate` returns a lazy sequence. So, the first call to `incr` function occurs outside of `binding` scope when you're trying to print the sequence.

Technically, your `incr` function is not free from side-effects just because it uses `^:dynamic` variable.

If you want to use `binding` with lazy sequences you should force the evaluation of your sequence somewhere inside of a `binding` scope, e.g.:

```clj
(binding [*step* 2]
  (doall (take 3 (iterate incr 1))))
; => (1 3 5)
```